# Issue with outputting to both a file and a variable in bash in one line

Tags: bash, ubuntu, pipe, stdout, stdin

I would like to use `$RANDOM` to create the following output and write it both to a file and to a variable all in one line.

```
123
24234
758
4893
```

My attempts are as follows, and none of them worked. I tried to *redirect* the standard output of `printf` to `read` and then *redirecting* to a `file`

```
$ read var < printf "%s\n" $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM > file
```

I also tried *piping* the standard output of `printf` to `read` then *redirecting* to a `file`:

```
$ printf "%s\n" $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM | read var > file
```

Could someone kindly help me understand where my issue is?

Answer (score 1):

`read` is used to grab input and assign them to variables. It does not produce output, so redirection would simply produce an empty file.

You can use the [`tee` command](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html) instead. It takes input from stdin, and writes output to stdout as well as one or more files.

Using `tee` and variable assignment, you could do:

```
$ variable=$(printf "%s " $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM $RANDOM | tee variable.txt)
```

Note that I have used "%s ", because you have asked for the output to be on a single line.

Which then gives you:

```
$ echo $variable
31738 28009 6462 15565

$ cat variable.txt
31738 28009 6462 15565
```

Comment: I get this error `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token \`|'`

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. You need `variable=$(printf...` for the assignment. I have corrected the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
var="$RANDOM
$RANDOM
$RANDOM
$RANDOM
$RANDOM"

printf '%s\n' "$var" > file
```

Or if you'd rather those numbers be elements of an array than the list being stored as newline delimited in a scalar variable:

```
var=("$RANDOM" "$RANDOM" "$RANDOM" "$RANDOM" "$RANDOM")
printf '%s\n' "${var[@]}" > file
```